# show that $H^1(Q,Z(P))=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose $P$ is a normal sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$. Now let $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $G$ and $Q=G/P$. Now suppose we have this commutative diagram

[image]

If $(|P|,|Q|)=1$ then I want to show that $H^1(Q,Z(P))=0$ when $Q$ acts on $Z(P)$ (centre of $P$) via conjugation.

But I am not familiar with homology and cohomology groups. I have done homological algebra on my own upto short exact sequences and Hom Tor functors including projective injective modules etc. But I need this to understand a proof I am doing on Normalizer problem. If some can break it down for me it will be helpful. Thanks.

P.S.- Paper- doi:10.1016/0022-4049(87)90028-4

Comment: The automophism phi seems to play no role in your question apart from being named. Also, notice that the orders of P and Q **are** coprime, there is no «if».

Answer (score 1):

If the orders of P and Q are coprime, so are the orders of Z(P) and Q. A very basic result in the cohomology of groups (which should be proved in all textbooks) is that

> if M is a G-module, then multiplication by |G| on H^\bullet(G,M) is zero.

In your case, multiplication by |G| on H^1(G,Z(P)) is also an isomorphism, because it is the map induced by multiplication by |G| on Z(P)

The only way that an endomorphism of an abelian group can be at the same time an isomorphism and zero is that the abelian group is zero itself.